# Why is Airflow crashing with INFO - "Task exited with return code -9"?

Tags: airflow

I have a big DAG running, however it's stopping with just that message, I couldn't figure out what is the error on the Airflow docs.

If that makes difference: My Airflow is running in a Rancher with a Helm chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about a way to reduce the size of all the memory possibilities. And the first try was load some number of lines instead of all the lines:

```py
serverCursor = conn.cursor("serverCursor")
serverCursor.execute(f'''select * from {ORIGIN_SCHEMA}.{table};''')

df = []
while True:
  records = serverCursor.fetchmany(size=50000)
  df = df + records
  if not records:
    break
serverCursor.close()
```

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually out of memory exception I think.

Comment: Why do you think that? Is there any summary with what that codes means?

Comment: airflow slack consensus.  i have searched for such a list to no avail.